# Pyspark coalesce vs coalesce: secretly the same or just unfortunate naming?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm reading [Spark: the definitive guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/spark-the-definitive/9781491912201/), and there is something I find confusing. The function `coalesce` is defined multiple times in enterily different contexts. I am wondering whether this is the same function, and I'm somehow just not seeing the link, or whether this is just an unfortuname naming issue.

On page 80, under the chapter 'Repartition and coalesce' it says:

> `Coalesce` [...] will not incur a full shuffle and will try to combine partitions.

As I understand it, this function will combine partitions until it has the desired number of partitions as indicated by the argument to the `coalesce` function.

On page 103, under the chapter 'Coalesce', it says:

> Spark includes a function to allow you to select the first non-null value from a set of columns by using the `coalesce` function.

As I understand it, this function will take a set of columns, and take all non-null values from the first column. Then for the null values it will look at the second column, and take all non-null values there, and so on.

**My questions**

- Is my understanding of these functions correct?
- How are these functions related? Is there some link I'm not seeing?
- If not why would they have the same name? (That seems really confusing to me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. To answer the question in your subject, I'd say *it's just a (not very) unfortunate naming*.

`coalesce()` as an RDD or Dataset method is designed to reduce the number of partitions, as you note. Google's dictionary says this:

> come together to form one mass or whole.

Or, (as a transitive verb):

> combine (elements) in a mass or whole.

`RDD.coalesce(n)` or [`DataFrame.coalesce(n)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.coalesce) uses this latter meaning.

[`pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) is, I believe, Spark's own implementation of the common SQL function `COALESCE`, which is implemented by many RDBMS systems, such as [MS SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617). 
As you note, this SQL function, which can be called both in program code directly or in SQL statements, returns the first non-null expression, just as the other SQL distributions' implementation.

In this case, `coalesce` is not alone. Such functions as `rtrim`, `trunc`, `date_add` all can be found in many other RDBMS distributions and (at least as far as I've seen) are pretty much standard.

There's a way to interpret "coalesce" in its "come together..." meaning as what this implementation is (the arguments coalesce into one, *null or the first non-null*)

In other words, the main link between the two is the meaning. Even if I'm not very familiar with the intimate implementation details, I can't guess that there's an implementation-level relationship between `RDD.coalesce` and `functions.coalesce`, like the one there would be between `RDD.coalesce` and `DataFrame.coalesce`.